# CakePHP: Unable to save associated model data (HasOne association)

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have successful able to save data in User and Profile model, the problem is in the Profile table only id and user_id is getting inserted, remaining fields in the profile eg, email, city are NULL. Please help me in sorting this, Please find the codes below:

Model:

### user.php:

```
class User extends AppModel {
public $name = 'User';

var $hasOne = array('Profile' =>
                    array('className'    => 'Profile',
                          'conditions'   => '',
                          'order'        => '',
                          'dependent'    =>  true,
                          'foreignKey'   => 'user_id'
                    )
              );
.....
```

UsersController.php:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
.....
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
                $this->request->data['Profile']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;
                $this->User->Profile->save($this->request->data);
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'homes','action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

View: add.ctp

```
            <?php echo $this->Form->create('User' , array('action' => 'add'));?>
            <fieldset>
                <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('username');
                    echo $this->Form->input('password');
                    echo $this->Form->input('profile.firstname');
                    echo $this->Form->input('profile.lastname');
                    echo $this->Form->input('profile.email');
                ?>
            </fieldset>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
```

Model: Profile.php:

```
class Profile extends AppModel {
public $name = 'Profile';
var $belongsTo = array('User' =>
                       array('className'  => 'User',
                             'conditions' => '',
                             'order'      => '',
                             'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
                       )
                 );
....
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Try capitalizing the `profile.field` like so: `echo $this->Form->input('Profile.firstname');` If that doesn't work, add the result of `debug($this->request->data);` In your `UsersController::add()` method in your question. Also, there is no city in your add.ctp.

Comment: wow.. thanks you very much @Wylie !!!! it worked.. broke my head for full night :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your form:

```
           <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('username');
                echo $this->Form->input('password');
                echo $this->Form->input('Profile.firstname');
                echo $this->Form->input('Profile.lastname');
                echo $this->Form->input('Profile.email');
            ?>
```

Also, the following if statement is overkill:

```
if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
```

clearly there is request data or you would not have gotten past the user save.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your form as Chuck Burgess says and additionally you can do:

```
if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
```

instead of:

```
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
```

So you don't need to save the Profile later.